# How to document pitfalls and gotchas in the code base?

Tags: documentation

What are some ways of documenting pitfalls and gotchas when working with a codebase with a team of developers? I'm working with a team of developers on a big codebase and there's lots of small little things that cause headaches and frustrations in code, configuration, and testing. It doesn't seem appropriate to put them into the github pages because they could be scattered across repositories and projects - so my question is what are some examples of documenting pitfalls and common gotchas?

Comment: Use inline code documentation like javadoc or such maybe?

Answer (score 6):

Quirks and hacks which are easy to explain could be explained in a form of a **comment**. After all, the purpose of the comments is exactly that—come to a rescue when one cannot or doesn't have enough resources to make unclear code clearer. The goal here is to help a programmer who's reading a given line of code (or series of lines) and asks himself what went so wrong in the past that it resulted in this specific piece of code.

Weird architecture decisions (which seemed right when they were taken, then appeared to be wrong, but nobody made the effort to refactor the codebase) should be documented in an **architecture document**. Put it in a location where anybody working on the project would find it easily, and make sure new programmers joining the project would necessarily read it.

In both cases, make sure you (and your coworkers) understand that **there is nothing normal in having a source code full of pitfalls and gotchas that need to be documented**.

Talk with your product owner to reserve a few hours or days per week for large refactoring tasks (i.e. changes at design or architecture level). If you don't, the project is doomed, as every other project where technical debt was left increasing.

Moreover, code-level refactoring should be your constant activity: whenever you work on a piece of code, ensure you follow the boy scout rule: “Leave your code better than you found it.” If a method is unclear because someone used one-letter names for the variables, don't keep it this way: rename them. It doesn't take long, and it will pay out the next time someone won't lose ten minutes trying to figure out how this method works. Most refactoring techniques are pretty simple and quick to implement, and many are very effective.

Comment: Just to add anecdotally: some managers/POs are allergic to the word "refactoring" and may shut any request for refactoring down using the "no time for that" argument. When faced with this, I often resort to simply factoring extra time in my estimates that account for refactoring. By considering the needed refactoring as part of the task's implementation (which in reality it should be if you want to avoid technical debt in the long run), you can often hide this detail from management/POs and still present them with a clear estimate that they are likely to agree to.

Answer (score 0):

### No quirks would be better

First and foremost, the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) applies:

> A typical formulation of the principle, from 1984, is: "If a necessary feature has a high astonishment factor, it may be necessary to **redesign the feature**."

In other words: **remove the quirks**. The time your developers lose on dealing with the quirks is likely to be bigger than the time needed for removing the quirk altogether.

[XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1205/) has a really handy guide to show you the rough numbers on how long you can justify spending time on fixing something based on how often you encounter it:

[image]

Taking a simple example, if your team runs into a particular quirk once a week (on average) and you spend 30 minutes on it (on average), and this product is expected to be used for the next 5 years, that gives you a whopping 21 hours or **just under 3 days** to work on fixing the quirk before you've spent more time than you've saved. Even if you encounter the same issue only on a monthly basis, that still gives you **about a day** to fix it.

Note that the time spent on a quirk very quickly adds up. Bugfixing, rerunning a comprehensive test playlist, communication during a daily standup, merge conflicts, training, reading the documentation on the quirk, ... Also note that training counts for double time because it's a time investment on both the trainer and the trainee's part.

### Documentation is not a [panacea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panacea_(medicine))

Don't get me wrong, documentation is essential, especially when you account for the 
[bus factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor), but documentation should not be your only line of defense.

Whenever they encounter an issue, no one is going to read through the entire documentation before consulting anyone else (nor should they). If they think the problem is new, they will spend time digging into it and it will take time (quirks tend to inherently be counterintuitive). If they don't think the problem is new, they're going to ask someone more experienced if there's a known resolution.

Documentation is great for referring to, but it doesn't inherently prevent developers distracting each other by asking about the problem. [Developer productivity tanks when they get distracted](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/190891/programmer_interrupted.php), and the duration of the distraction is a surprisingly negligible factor here (whether the distraction takes seconds, minutes or hours).

> **No Distractions**
>   Another approach for getting into the zone is to avoid all distractions. Some people are more sensitive to distraction than others, but we should always aim to minimise the kinds of distraction that pulls our mind out of what we're currently doing. **Avoiding the context switching cost is a big win**.

The rest of [the article](https://lifehacker.com/what-is-the-zone-anyway-5920484) is less relevant here but it touches on the importance of not switching context if you want to keep productivity up.

### When you need to document

But sometimes, quirks are too ingrained, or you're unable to convince management to refactor the code. These things happen. And when they do, documentation is the least you can do (cynical pun intended).

For one-off quirks (i.e. located on a single line or file), inline comments are the most easily noticed warnings. This ensures that developers who look at the quirky code are immediately alerted of the quirk.

If the quirks are endemic to the architecture and thus spread across an entire layer (or worse; multiple layers), inline comments don't cut it. You don't want to pepper them across your codebase.
Here, it becomes more appropriate to have a **developer guideline** for the project which outlines common pitfalls (among other things). Arseni's answer calls this an "architecture document" but the gist is the same.

As a consultant, I tend to write these guidelines for projects where I'm unable to assist development or review the code on an ongoing basis (whether it be a limited contract duration or other responsibilities). The document contains more than just pitfalls, but the overall purpose of the content is to steer developers in the right direction in regards to implementation, separation of responsibilities over multiple layers, dependencies and the aforementioned quirks, pitfalls and FAQ.

This may seem like overkill, but in my job context I'm often writing these for teams where bad practice is the norm or teams that struggle with consistency and/or good practice guidelines. Given your situation of having *"lots of small little things that cause headaches and frustrations in code, configuration, and testing"*, that is not too dissimilar and similar documentation may be warranted if you cannot continuously rely on the guiding hand of a more experienced developer/reviewer to avoid the quirks.